# how to run for loop conditionally, with certain values omitted , PHP

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I want to run this loop and place values in new variables defined inside for loop

stage= stage1, stage3, stagexx

```
for ($i=0;$i<=count($name);$i++) {
$current[$i]  = $count[$i];
$stage = array_replace($stage, $stage1);
}
```

I have to run several for loops for my script.

The above for loop 
I want to run it First for all count($name) ,  If certain conditions are met.

**Example:**

**I want to 

omit $name[3] and run the loop again.

or 

omit $name[6] and run the loop again.  to place the new values in**

```
$current[$i]  = $count[$i];
$stage = array_replace($stage, $stage1);
```

**Resulted Values:**

At the End , I want to get new values for below mentioned variables based on omitted values, When I omit any value, variables will change their values are well.

```
$current[$i]  = $count[$i];
$stage = array_replace($stage, $stage1);
```

or

```
**omit $name[3]** 
  $current[$i]  = $count[$i];
    $stage = array_replace($stage, $stage4);
```

or

```
**omit $name[xx]** 
  $current[$i]  = $count[$i];
    $stage = array_replace($stage, $stagexx);
```

Edit:

If I ommited values, what will new face of for loop.

**for example:**

if ($i <> 3 ) 
I want to run for loop again , and omit the value = 3

```
for ($i=0;$i<=count($name);$i++) {
    $current[$i]  = $count[$i];
    $stage = array_replace($stage, $stage1);
    }
```

I want to know how to write for loop again with omitted values ?

Answer (score 0):

For this:

```
**omit $name[3]** 
  $current[$i]  = $count[$i];
```

Just exclude it

```
**omit $name[3]** 
  if ($i<>3)  $current[$i]  = $count[$i];
```

There is no reason that won't work.

EDIT:  You don't modify the FOR loop.  You set a condition inside of it:

```
for ($i=0;$i<=count($name);$i++) {
    if ($i<>3)  $current[$i]  = $count[$i];  //only run this if it's not=3
    //$current[$i]  = $count[$i];  
    $stage = array_replace($stage, $stage1);
    }
```

Comment: with this , it should not affect the value of $i=3 , and rest new values should be saved .. is this true with your code ???

Comment: It's not setting $i.  It's just checking its state.  So this won't break anything.  furthermore, you can set that omission to whatever you want.  It's hardcoded as "3" in this example.  You can set that as a variable before you start the loop.  Omit whatever one you want.

Comment: what will be format of for loop  for  ($i<>3 ) .. As in first instance of loop i will gather all the values ,, and then run a new loop with omitted values .

how to write the new for loop so  that i does no read the value of  ($i<>3 )  , The omitted one  ???

Comment: See edit to my answer.  I really don't understand what you're trying to do.  I'm just trying to give you an idea based on what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip execution within the loop for certain cases and still continue the loop, you should use the continue statement. For example:

```
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i) {
        if ($i == 2)
            continue;
        print "$i\n";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the question a bit difficult to grasp. Are you able to put this block of code inside a function and parametrize the function such that you have (for example) a list of indices to omit?

```
function yourLoopFunction($namesArr, $omitIndicesArr){
    $current = array();

    ... // where stage, stage1 come from

    for ($i=0; $i < count($name); $i++) {
        if (!in_array($i, $omitIndicesArr){
            $current[$i]  = $count[$i];
            $stage = array_replace($stage, $stage1);
        }
    }

    return $current;
}
```